# one to many relation in an embeeded form symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I have a bidirectionnal relation in my entityA with entity User such as the relation in the entity A is one to many.

```
/**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="xxx\UserBundle\Entity\User",mappedBy="entityA",cascade={"persist"})
   */
  private $users;
```

I want to add an entity User to entity A with an embeeded form
So here is the code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {       
        $builder             ->add('users', new UserType()) 
    ;
    }
```

The problem now is that I don't get the entity user in the database and I get the following warning

```
Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php line 1563
```

Comment: search the doc for collection type and use the type option to configure what form to use.

Comment: Please post your controller code.